# Why was my ANSWERED question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, off-topic

I asked a question on stackoverflow.com saying this:

> I need to check if a user has already clicked a button… I have a
>   button in my menu with a “promo code” inside… I need to check if user
>   already clicked it so i can tell him (the next time he clicks it) “You
>   already redeemed this promo code!” How do i do that? I need only the
>   piece of code where i can check for button clicked.
>
> ```
> PS: alredy searched the whole web for this!
>
> Thank you!
> ```

After 2 REALLY GOOD answers that solved my issue, a moderator put my answer on hold leaving this comment:

> Wow. You searched the whole web and found nothing on this?

Comment: *Please notice that I omitted the surname for privacy*. Right, because there are [hundreds of diamond moderators named Andrew on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)...

Comment: Link to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303596/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-already-clicked-a-button

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i omitted also the name...

Comment: @MartijnPieters that Ali Baba really gets to me some times :-)

Comment: @user2606414: The moderator names are public knowledge. There are only 16, and we kinda need to see the closed question *anyway*. It is not as if we won't find out. But you could have made this less of an attack on the moderator and more a general question of 'why was my question closed, I even got two good answers' and not need to talk about *any single person* that closed your question.

Comment: It was not an attack to the moderator! I am a moderator (in other site) and i know we should keep the calm in the forum… It was just to let you all know it is a real question and not a “why?” “why?” “why?"

Comment: I never mind being called out by name. My "powers" should come with very public accountability. That said, your effort to concentrate on the "what" instead of the "who" is very much appreciated.

Comment: and for the record, my comment left on the question was mostly a bit of a joke aimed at the "whole web" comment, and I loved your response to it.

Comment: Is this a joke or are you serious? Sorry but i am italian and i don’t really understand if you joke! ;)
When i said “the whole web” I was saying that i searched for everything and i didn’t find anything…

Comment: By the way, I just found out that the ♦ means you are a diamond moderator! Congrats!

Comment: my two comments above are serious, and all good natured :)

Comment: I cast the final reopen vote just now due to the edit, by the way!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The moderator likely responded to user flags; at least one, perhaps more members of the community flagged your post as off-topic.

Before the moderator acted on the flag, two answers were posted. This happens, not everyone is aware or agrees with off-topic close reasons.

That said, your question shows 0 effort on your own. A claim that you searched the web is *not enough* to show that you have made any attempts at writing your own code. The solution was to use a simple boolean flag, which indicates the problem wasn't that hard to begin with.

Comment: But i actually wrote my code! I didn’t share it because I didn’t think StackOverFlow needed it! :( Is there any way to get the answer back? Maybe editing it and adding my code?

Comment: Yes, *on hold* is not a permanent state. Do fill in your own attempts; that makes your question useful to *others* as well, perhaps they could find your question in the future and not have to ask it *again*.

Comment: @user2606414: When you edit your question, it is automatically entered into the 'reopen' queue and people will review to see if your question is good enough to be reopened.

Comment: Ok, i’ll see what can i do. Thank you, Lorenzo

Comment: I added my code… hope that someone will take it out from “on hold”… I am really sorry and sad because I did all this mess...

Answer (score 5):

Just because the question was answered doesn't mean the question was suitable for this site. Read the on hold reason:

> "Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

We expect you to show your work. Tell us what you've tried and what issues you had before you asked here. Even if it didn't work, or didn't even compile, you should at least show us that you tried *something*. Please include your attempt to solve the problem along with the description of your problem.

Comment: I read that too… In fact I provided the right answer in no time… I’ll share my code in future posts but is there any way to take my question “out-of-hold”? EDIT: Martijn answered to me… Thank you

Comment: @user2606414 Yes, as *Martijn Pieters* [suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193776/why-was-my-answered-question-putted-on-hold/193778#comment607583_193777), you can always edit any post of yours that hasn't been deleted or locked. If you add information and to your question to demonstrate your earlier attempts it may well be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Many times people will answer a question even while voting to close it to be polite and at least offer some sort of path to resolution even though the question is not a good fit for that particular exchange.

That it was put on hold is not mutually exclusive to the question being answered. There are even some long running highly voted questions which get closed, or even deleted, in the process of determining what characteristics should be avoided in questions.